# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery

Tags: stored-procedures

```
declare @ProductDetails as table(ProductName nvarchar(200),ProductDescription nvarchar(200),
Brand nvarchar(200),
Categry  nvarchar(200),
Grop nvarchar(200),
MRP decimal,SalesRate decimal,CurrentQuantity decimal,AvailableQty decimal)

declare @AvailableQty table(prcode nvarchar(100),Aqty decimal)

declare @CloseStock table(pcode nvarchar(100),
Cqty decimal)

insert into @CloseStock
select PCODE ,
0.0
from producttable

insert into @AvailableQty
select PCODE ,
0.0
from producttable

--Current Qty
--OpenQty
update @CloseStock set Cqty=((OOQTY+QTY+SRRQTY+PYQTY)-(STQTY+PRRQTY))
from
(
select PC.PCODE as PRODUCTCODE,
--Opening
(select case when SUM(PU.Quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(PU.Quantity) end as Q from ProductOpeningYearEnd PU
where PC.PCODE=PU.ProductName) as OOQTY,
--Purchase
(select case when SUM(PU.quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(PU.quantity) end as Q from purchase PU
where PC.PCODE=PU.prdcode ) as QTY,
--Sales
(select case when SUM(ST.QUANTITY)is null then 0 else SUM(ST.QUANTITY)end as Q2 from salestable ST
where PC.PCODE=ST.PRODUCTCODE and ST.status!='cancel' )as STQTY,
--Physical Stock
(select case when SUM(PS.Adjustment)is null then 0 else SUM(PS.Adjustment)end as Q3 from physicalstock PS
where PC.PCODE=PS.PCODE )as PYQTY,
--Sales Return
(select case when SUM(SR.quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(SR.quantity)end as Q3 from salesreturn SR
where PC.PCODE=SR.prdcode )as SRRQTY,
--Purchase Return
(select case when SUM(PR.quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(PR.quantity)end as Q3 from purchasereturn PR
where PC.PCODE=PR.prdcode )as PRRQTY

from producttable PC
group by PC.PCODE
)t
where PCODE=t.PRODUCTCODE

--Available
update @AvailableQty set Aqty=((CCqty-GIQty)+(GOQty))
--((OOQTY+QTY+SRRQTY+PYQTY)-(STQTY+PRRQTY))
from
(
select PC.PCODE as PRODUCTCODE,
--GoodsIn
(select case when SUM(GI.quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(GI.quantity) end as Q from goodsin GI
where PC.PCODE=GI.productcode) as GIQty,
--GoodsOut
(select case when SUM(GUT.quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(GUT.quantity) end as Q from goodsout GUT
where PC.PCODE=GUT.productcode ) as GOQty,
--Current Stock
(select CS.Cqty as Q from @CloseStock CS 
where PC.PCODE=CS.pcode ) as CCqty
from producttable PC
group by PC.PCODE
)t
where prcode=t.PRODUCTCODE

insert into @ProductDetails
select PCODE,[DESCRIPTION],BRAND,CATEGORY,DEPARTMENT,MRP,SALERATE,0,0
from producttable

update @ProductDetails set CurrentQuantity=pcqty,AvailableQty=acqty
from
(
select pt.ProductName as pn,cs.Cqty as pcqty,ac.Aqty as acqty from @ProductDetails pt
inner join @CloseStock cs on pt.ProductName=cs.pcode
inner join @AvailableQty ac on pt.ProductName=ac.prcode     
)t
where ProductName=t.pn

select * from @ProductDetails

end
```

This not working when productable in pcode field add ant (-.&) this kind of symbol i want to even allow in pcode field, 
please help me how i can allow any symbol in query

(problem with this code)
update @AvailableQty set Aqty=((CCqty-GIQty)+(GOQty))
    from
    (
    select PC.PCODE as PRODUCTCODE,
    --GoodsIn
    (select case when SUM(GI.quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(GI.quantity) end as Q from goodsin GI
    where PC.PCODE=GI.productcode) as GIQty,
    --GoodsOut
    (select case when SUM(GUT.quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(GUT.quantity) end as Q from goodsout GUT
    where PC.PCODE=GUT.productcode ) as GOQty,
    --Current Stock
    (select CS.Cqty as Q from @CloseStock CS 
    where PC.PCODE=CS.pcode ) as CCqty
    from producttable PC
    group by PC.PCODE
    )t
    where prcode=t.PRODUCTCODE

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that message but this `Cqty=((OOQTY+QTY+SRRQTY+PYQTY)-(STQTY+PRRQTY))` won't work. You're referencing INLINE VIEW aliases as though they were FIELDs. Those fields aren't addressable in any case since you're not selecting them in the inline view `t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here isn't with the symbols you're using, it's that you are assigning the value of a subquery to a single column in the result set. For example:

```
(select case when SUM(PR.quantity)is null then 0 else SUM(PR.quantity)end as Q3 from purchasereturn PR
where PC.PCODE=PR.prdcode )as PRRQTY
```

Note that this is allowed only if the subquery returns only a single value; otherwise, we don't know which of the values should be assigned to the column.

If you expect your subqueries to return multiple values and you just want an arbitrary one, use `TOP 1` in the subquery to only return 1 value. Otherwise, you'll have to debug each subquery to figure out which returns multiple results and is causing the issue.

Comment: Value problem is only the (-.,) this symbol had with character that is problem subquery return show error. in this query want to allow also those symbol.